# Serializing in java file io

Tags: java

Consider the following four hypothetical classes to be defined in a project: A, B, C, and D. A will be the parent class of B and C. C will have a data member variable of class D. In this project, we want to store C objects in a file using serialization approach, that is we want to create binary files that contain C objects. Which classes of this project must implement the interface Serializable?

Comment: Is there any state in A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C class should implement `Serializable`.

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.

You cas read the official documentation of the interface :

[Interface Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

On the other hand, for your D attribut you have to options:

- Implement Serializable, if you want to send it
- Make it `transient`, if you wan't to send it

Comment: How about D? As it is contained in C, does it also need to be serializable?

Comment: I forget that, you need to make the class D Serializable otherwise you will have an java.io.NotSerializableException